# Split larger file into small ones based on regex, 2nd opinion

Tags: perl

Okay, so I've read of different ways of doing this, but I just want to check if there was an unseen problem with the way I've done it, or if there is a better way (perhaps grep?).

Here is my working code:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $chapternumber;
open my $corpus, '<', "/Users/jon/Desktop/chpts/chpt1-8/Lifeprocessed.txt" or die $!;
while (my $sentence = <$corpus>) 
    {
    if ($sentence =~ /\~\s(\d*F*[\.I_]\w+)\s/ ) 
        {
        $chapternumber = $1;
        $chapternumber =~ s/\./_/;
        }

    open my $outfile, '>>', "/Users/jon/Desktop/chpts/chpt$chapternumber.txt" or die $!;
    print $outfile $sentence;
    }
```

The file is a textbook, and I have denoted new chapters by: `~ 1.1  Organisms Have Changed over Billions of Years  1.1.` or `~ 15Intro ...` or `~ F_14`I want that to be the beginning of a new file: chpt1_1.txt (or other chpt15Intro etc....). Which ends when I find the next chapter delimiter.

1 option: Perhaps instead of line-by-line, just getting the whole block like this? :

```
 local $/ = "~";
 open...
 while...
 next unless ($sentenceblock =~ /\~\s([\d+F][\.I_][\d\w]+)\s/);
....
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, the good things:

```
enabled strict and warnings
using 3-arg open and lexical filehandles
checking the return value from open()
```

But your regex makes no sense at all.

```
~ is not "meta" in regexes, so it does not need escaping
. is not "meta" in a character class, so it does not need escaping
[\d+F] is equivalent to [+F\d] (what is the "F" for? + matches a literal plus character in a character class, it does NOT mean "one or more" here
[\.I_] what is the "I" for? What is the underscore for?
[\d\w] is equivalent to [\w] and even to just \w
```

Your code calls open() way more times that it needs to.

tr/// is better than s/// for working with individual characters.

Hopefully this will put you onto the right track:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $outfile;
while (<DATA>) {
    if ( my($chapternumber) = /^~\s([\d.]+)/) {
        $chapternumber =~ tr/./_/;
        close $outfile if $outfile;
        open $outfile, '>', "chpt$chapternumber.txt"
            or die "could not open 'chpt$chapternumber.txt' $!";
    }
    print {$outfile} $_;
}

__DATA__
~ 1.1 Organisms Have Changed over Billions of Years 1.1
stuff
about changing
organisms
~ 1.2 Chapter One, Part Two 1.2
part two
stuff is here
```

Comment: Okay, before I use your great answer, I've been trying to fix the regex which doesn't search for what I want. Thanks though!

Comment: No `O_EXCL`? :)/2 Actually, the thing I would add is the encoding. I’ve striven for some time now to stomp out the idea of “just a plain text file”.  An appropriate `use open` pragma would be good enough for the new files, although not for `DATA`. You don’t *have* to name them "foo.ascii", "foo.latin1", "foo.utf8" or whatever – although that can work well — but just blind foo.txt files have caused me so much grief these past few years that I have come to despise them.

Comment: Tom: I think maybe it's time for a book, and you seem to be qualified in that regard.  If I saw 'Unicode', 'Perl', and 'Tom Christainsen' on the same cover I'd pick it up.  A sketch of an animal on the front would be the final straw.

Comment: @tadmc: Haven't tested, but maybe you made a mistake with =//, should be =~ ? (details) Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Comment: @Jon No, @tadmc’s `= /⋯/` is just fine: it’s matching the implicit variable, `$_` in a list assignment in scalar context. However, this does show one of the flaws of this style: you actually have to *write* `$_` at one point, which I would never do because I feel that Perl’s default are such that if you find yourself having to manually say the implicit variable’s name, you’re doing something suboptimally, since it should just be the default. And it *would* be, were I doing it. But that requires more space, and more importantly, pretty formatting, than is available to me in this comment. :)

Comment: `close(OUTFILE) || die "close $outfilename failed: $!" if defined fileno(OUTFILE)` is what I would do, and a simple `print OUTFILE`, but that requires changes to the `open`. Actually, I’d `use autodie` and dispense with manual error checking, since that is too easily forgotten (as it indeed was here, an omission that leads to a subtle heisenbug).

Comment: Thanks! Learned a lot here, some over my head, but that's a good thing. :)

Answer (score 1):

hm.. perhaps csplit?

Save the following into the file e.g. splitter.sh

```
csplit -s -f tmp - '/^~ [0-9][0-9]*\./'
ls tmp* | while read file
do
    title=($(head -1 $file))
    mv $file chpt${title[1]//./_}.txt
done
```

and use it

```
bash splitter.sh < book.txt
```

Comment: Cool, I'll look into this, haven't heard of csplit before.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just slurp in the entire contents?  Then you can just match against each chapter title.  The `/m` makes the `^` match against all starts of lines within the multi-line string, and the `/g` matches the same pattern against all matches in the `while` until no more matches appear.  `man perlre`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $corpus, '<', '/Users/jon/..../Lifeprocessed.txt' or die $!;
undef $/;
my $contents = <$corpus>;
close($corpus);

while ( $contents =~ /^\~\s([\d+F][\.I_][\d\w]+)\s/mg ) {
    ( my $chapternumber = $1 ) =~ s/\./_/;
    open my $outfile, '>>', "/Users/jon/Desktop/chpts/chpt$chapternumber.txt" or die $!;
    print $outfile $sentence;
    close $outfile;
}
```

Comment: Because this is utterly infeasible for many if not most corpora. Consider the BioThesaurus, which is 6,146,949,632 bytes **and of mixed encoding** (although that aspect is an error).  The PubMed Central Open Access collection has 11G, although that at least is all in a known encoding. You just can’t throw slurpy at some of these.

Comment: @tchrist - Egads, I certainly didn't realize the nature of this problem domain.  Line/para/section-at-a-time is certainly the better choice here.